# Integer overflow in boolean expressions

Tags: c++, overflow, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I have the following c++ code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long long int currentDt = 467510400*1000000;
    long long int addedDt = 467510400*1000000;
    if(currentDt-addedDt >= 0 && currentDt-addedDt <= 30*24*3600*1000000)
    {
                cout << "1" << endl;
                cout << currentDt-addedDt << endl;

    }       
    if(currentDt-addedDt > 30*24*3600*1000000 && currentDt-addedDt <= 60*24*3600*1000000)
    {
                cout << "2" << endl;
                cout << currentDt-addedDt << endl;

    }       
    if(currentDt-addedDt > 60*24*3600*1000000 && currentDt-addedDt <= 90*24*3600*1000000)
    {
                cout << "3" << endl;
                cout << currentDt-addedDt << endl;

    }       

   return 0;
}
```

Firstly, I get a warning for integer overflow, which strikes me as odd because the number 467510400*1000000 falls well within the range of a long long int, does it not? Secondly, I get the following output:

```
1
0
3
0
```

If in both cases currentDt-addedDt evaluates to 0, how could the third if statement possibly evaluate to true?

Comment: What happens if you use `467510400ll * 1000000ll` etc? Maybe the compiler is multiplying them as `int`s.

Comment: `long long int`, yes, but math on all of those constants is likely being performed as `int`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`467510400*1000000` is within the range of `long long`, but it's not within the range of `int`. Since both literals are of type `int`, the type of the product is also of type `int` - and that will overflow. Just because you're assigning the result to a `long long` doesn't change the value that gets assigned. For the same reason that in:

```
double d = 1 / 2;
```

`d` will hold `0.0` and not `0.5`.

You need to explicitly cast one of the literals to be of a larger integral type. For example:

```
long long int addedDt = 467510400LL * 1000000;
```

Comment: This makes sense. I would also have to do the same to the literals in the if statements themselves too, right? @Barry

Comment: @Danzo Why not store them in `const long long` variables and use those instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
   long long int currentDt = 467510400ll*1000000ll;
   long long int addedDt = 467510400ll*1000000ll;
```

Note the two lowercase letter "l"s following the digits. These make your constants long long. C++ normally interpret strings of digits in source as plain `int`s.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that all of your integer literals are `int`.  When you multiply them they overflow giving you the unexpected behavior.  To correct this you can make them `long long` literals using `467510400ll * 1000000ll`

Answer (score 0):

It because

```
60*24*3600*1000000 evaluates to -25526272
```

use

```
60LL*24LL*3600LL*1000000LL
```

instead (note the 'LL' suffix)

Comment: It doesn't have to evaluate to that.

Comment: @NeilKirk it does in VS2012 debugger

Comment: Signed integer overflow is undefined

Comment: Also 64-bit `int` compilers are possible.

Comment: @NeilKirk, true, but the standard default integer type (without suffix specifiers) in C++ is `int` not `int64`. So literal computation of as posted will evaluate using `int` thus the overflow

Comment: The standard allows `int` to be 64-bits, in which case this `int` calculation will not overflow.

Comment: @NeilKirk, true. So it depends on the compiler doesn't it? And probably whether you're compiling for 32 or 64 bit processors.

Comment: Yes it depends on the compiler what it evaluates to. The processor doesn't matter. Many compilers still use 32-bit `int` even for 64-bit targets.

Comment: @NeilKirk, the processor bitness only matters as the **target** of compilation. Hence the `sizeof(int)` will be different and thus overflow or not constant expressions. Hence it's always better to use the correct suffix when doing constant expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You have tagged this with C++.

My minimal change to your code would use the c++ static_cast to promote at least one of the literal numbers (of any overflow generating expression) to an int64_t (found in include file cstdint).

Example:

```
//          0         true
if(currentDt-addedDt  >= 0     

&&   // true because vvvv

//          0        true
   currentDt-addedDt <= 30*24*3600*static_cast<int64_t>(1000000))
//                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

(for test 1, the result of the if clause is true.
 for test 2 and 3 is false)

Upon finding the static_cast, the compiler promotes the 3 other integers (in the clause) to int64_t, and thus generates no warnings about overflow.

Yes, it adds a lot of chars for being, in some sense, 'minimal'.

Comment: And I do not object to LL suffix, but perhaps these literal constants are used elsewhere, and do not need to be bigger than they are declared.